# Localized string resources not loading in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, localization, cultureinfo

I'm seeing the strangest thing.  When running our program in the VS 2010 Debugger, I'm able to switch to use any of our other culture's resource strings and they load just fine in the UI.  However, when building and running as a standalone WPF app, only thing like numbers (0.000 -> 0,000) in text boxes are changing.  The code we use to dynamically reset to another culture is:

```
    private void ResetCulture(string culture)
    {
        // Reset the culture and reload the resources
        var ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Messenger.Default.Send<CultureInfo>(ci);
    }
```

Note: Messenger comes from the MVVM Light toolkit (we're using this code for both WPF and Silverlight).  Finally, I should mention this code works perfectly fine under Silverlight.

Anyone have any idea why WPF isn't cooperating by loading the new culture's resource strings?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Where are the resources coming from? Do you see a different behavior when running within VS if you uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox in the project properties under Debug? I ask because that causes a difference in behavior. When that is checked VS preloads all the referenced assemblies. When that is unchecked it is more like normal runtime where only the assemblies that are used are loaded.

Comment: The resources are all string resources coming from .resx files, with Forms.resx being the parent, and Forms.<culture>.resx being all the children (along with the Forms.Designer.cs file).  I checked our Debug settings for the WPF project and the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option was already unchecked.  Other thoughts?

Comment: You mention when running in the debugger. Does it work when you run within VS without the debugger attached? i.e. Ctrl+F5 So VS is generating resource assemblies for you then - i.e. you have subfolder like de-DE\fooassembly.resources.dll. Are you distributing those and keeping the same folder structure?

Comment: Running with CTRL+F5 works just fine.  All of the strings are also embedded resources.

Comment: Interesting.  Problem solved (for the most part).  I copied all of the culture-specific subdirectories (de, es, fr, etc.) to the directory where our WPF installs to and when I ran the installed WPF app, it picked up the strings.  I guess this shows I'm new to using the culture stuff.  I thought by specifying embedded resource, that the strings would all be built into a single dll or the .exe itself.  I guess not.  Now I need to modify our installer to pick up those files.  Thanks for the help.  It led me down the right path to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the application. to new resources can be load to memory.

antonio